# How can you determine a Spore save game's difficulty level?

Tags: spore

I started a game in Spore, and I'm now at creature stage.  However, I can't remember which difficulty level I selected when I started my game (at cell stage).  Is there any way for me to find out which difficulty level this save game is running at?  Is there any info display I can look at that will tell me, or failing that, are there any gameplay clues that will tell me whether the difficulty level for this save game is Easy, Normal, or Hard?

Comment: On the galaxy load screen, are the planets colour-coded by difficulty? I know you can tell by spaceship health http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Health but I'm not sure other than that. Maybe in the creature history screen?

Comment: If you can finish Tribal stage then you aren't playing on hard.

Comment: Erm, I've finished the tribal stage several times on hard difficulty.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check the difficulty level once the game's been created, until the space stage where your spaceship health differs, depending on difficulty. You could however, make an educated guess - based on how hard you're finding it.

Next time, just try to remember it (writing it down may help...)